# Absolutely positioning an element along a path based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to position a div element over a sine wave that is used as its path. As the user scrolls, the callback should be able to calculate the `left` and `top` properties of the `Ball` along the sine wave. I'm having trouble with the positioning. I'm using `Math.abs` for the y-axis and I'm adding 8 (or -8) pixels to handle the x-axis.

Another thing I've noticed is that the scroll event listener callback sometimes missed certain breakpoints. I've console logged the scroll position and its true, the callback is either executed every ~3 pixels or the browser throttles the `scroll` event on its own for some reason (which I can understand, there's no point in tracking every pixel scroll).

Anyway, I'm wondering why my current approach isn't working and if there's a better solution to this problem? I feel like there's too much stuff going on and that this could be achieved in a better way. Here's what I have:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const lineHeight = 200;
export default React.memo(() => {
  const [top, setTop] = React.useState(275);
  const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(0);
  const [previousPosition, setPreviousPosition] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => { const s = skrollr.init() }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [previousPosition, left]);

  const handleScroll = React.useCallback(() => {
    const pageYOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    const isMovingForward = pageYOffset > previousPosition;

    setPreviousPosition(window.pageYOffset);
    setTop(lineHeight - Math.abs(lineHeight - pageYOffset));

    if (isMovingForward) {
      if (pageYOffset > 575 && pageYOffset <= 770) setLeft(left + 8);
    } else {
      if (pageYOffset <= 770 && pageYOffset >= 575) setLeft(left - 8)
    }
  }, [previousPosition, left]);

  return (
    <Main>
      <Container
        data-500p="transform: translateX(0%)"
        data-1000p="transform: translateX(-800%)"
      >
        <Content>
          <WaveContainer>
            <Wave src="https://www.designcrispy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Sine-Wave-Curve.png" />
          </WaveContainer>
          <BallContainer top={top} left={left}>
            <Ball />
          </BallContainer>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    </Main>
  );
});

const Main = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fffee1;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative;
`;

const Wave = styled.img`
  width: 600px;
`;

const WaveContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 45%;
`;

const Ball = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
`;

const BallContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.25s;
  ${({ top, left }) => `top: ${top}px; left: ${left}px;`};
`;
```

I'm using [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to handle the fixed canvas + scroll length.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-sea-wwugv?file=/src/Road.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your codesandbox so it does what you need: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nobel-64odf (I hope)

I should add that I changed various things about your code:

- No need to set up new scroll listener every time a left or previous
  position changes. What is all the code about previous position and
  deciding if page is being scrolled up or down? I removed it.
- The animation was being throttled due to transition: 0.25s on your
  Ball container. In order to calculate the ball position relatively to
  image - sinusoide, I moved them into the same container.
- To calculate exact position of ball, WAVE_WIDTH and WAVE_HEIGHT
  constants need to be used, and proper mathematics need to be used -
  the sinusoide on image seems to be long of 2,5 periods. However 2,58
  was better constant to fit the animation. I'd try using different
  sinusoide and figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can support [offset-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path) (not available on IE or Safari, apparently), I would strongly suggest moving as much of this as you can to CSS and SVG based animation. Here is a vanilla JS example - the only thing you actually have to calculate here is what percent along you want the animation to be, which could be based on any arbitrary scroll criteria:

```js
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const winHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset;
  const pc = (pageOffset*2/winHeight)*100;
  
  ball.style.offsetDistance = `${pc}%`;
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 200vh;
}

.container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.ball {
  offset-path: path("M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <svg>
      <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The drawbacks to this are that you'll have to recreate your specific path using SVG, which could take a bit of learning time if you aren't familiar with the syntax. The path is also not going to be responsive to screen width so you'd have to recalculate it a few times if that is important to you.

If that's not an option then you're basically going to have to write or find a script which is capable of generating a given sine wave, and then calculating coordinate position along it based on percentage. If it's not exact then it's never going to line up properly.